# how to create a Database design for access control and tracking?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Planing to create Access control system. Keeping an education institution in mind i created the Perimeter Tables like Main Gate, Zones, Building , Levels, Sections, Rooms(each table with foreign key relation).....Now i wish to create department table and employee tables, But how can i define a department to a particular perimeter. Because as the user the department can be a room or an entire building. Giving all the perimeter table foreign Key into the department table is not an apt way i guess. I also want the access to be in a path, don't want to authorized, if the user come to a Checkpoint through different point. I am newbie in database design, there might be a simple way i did not think of.. Please do help with a optimal design idea to create the above.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the point of creating a hierarchy of securable locations is to manage who should have access to which locations, you are better off managing all of these locations in a **single table** with an involuted foreign key (self-referencing relationship).

Consider the following ERD:

[image: ERD]

Here you have security zones that can contain other security zones.  People are granted access to the appropriate zones.  Access to a lower level zone implies access to all of the zones that contain the lower level zone.

Using an involuted foreign key implies having to deal with hierarchical data, which can be a nuisance in SQL.  To ease hierarchy navigation, I suggest using **visitation numbers** as I described at length in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420885/how-do-i-design-a-database-to-store-properties-selecting-attributes-by-synonyms/7423459#7423459).

One thing to consider in any kind of access control system is minimizing the amount of data to be maintained by your security administrator.  Many people will have the same access rules.  For this reason, you may want to expand on the above ERD to use **role based security** in which *groups* not *individuals* are granted access to zones and individuals are granted access to groups.  See my answer to [this question on dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12046/what-is-a-basic-model-for-making-a-database-with-users-and-groups/12107#12107) for more about role based security.  If it might help, you could use a mixture of role-based and individual access rules.

Another option to consider is that your ACCESS table could include both *allow* and *disallow* flags.  These could be used to allow access to a larger area while specifically forbidding access to a smaller area that is contained within. This approach could reduce the amount of data that needs to be managed for each person.

Comment: Thank You so much @joel. The visitation numbering is a good way to group.