# Database Design - Catalogue - Range - Product

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Can anyone suggest a database design for the following:

A user can make a catalogue
Within a catalogue a user can make a range - i.e. a range of products
Within a range a user can add multiple products
Within a range a user can add multiple ranges -> range->range->range all with products in them.

I currently have in my database -

catalogue_range with - id, name, description
and
catalogue_product with - id, range_id, name, description

can anyone see what I'm trying to produce?

My aim is to be able to make multiple catalogue ranges within a catalogue range and add multiple products to each of these catalogue ranges.

Here is my current SQL:

```
`catalogue_range` (
      `id` char(40) NOT NULL,
      `profile_id` char(40) NOT NULL,
      `type` enum('pdf','db') DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` enum('new','draft','live') NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
      `description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
      `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `profile_id` (`profile_id`)
    )

`catalogue_product` (
  `id` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `catalogue_id` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `order` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `catalogue_id` (`catalogue_id`)
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the sql for the best design you have so far.  (Indent it four space so it's formatted properly.)

Comment: updated sql as requested, see original post

Comment: And do you want products to be able to be present in multiple catalogues?

Comment: yeah, so many catalogues, many ranges, many products, but you can have products within catalogues too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. catalogue(**catalogue id**, your private attributes)
2. product(**product id**, #catalogue id, your private attributes)
3. range(**range id**, #range id parent, your private attributes)
4. product range(**#product id**, **#range id**)

You will need stored procedures/applicative algorithms to compile:

- the list of product of a range (to calculate recursive sqls mysql doesn't offer analytic functions as oracle does)
- the list of ranges of a catalogue/range

Hope it helps.
S.

Comment: thanks for the solutions, i've used a very similar way to what you have said, the only way i've done it differently is  by merging the catalogues and ranges, because effectively, they are both the same in my use. Thanks C!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a product can only exist in one catalogue at a time, your design is almost alright as it is.  What you are missing is a **recursive foreign key** on `catalogue_range`.  Add something like the following to your `catalogue_range` table definition:

```
`parent_range_id` char(40) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`parent_range_id`) REFERENCES catalogue_range(`id`)
```

The top level range(s) for any given user will have a NULL `parent_range_id`, others will refer to the containing range.  Note that hierarchies aren't necessarily easy to work with in SQL.  You may also want to look into techniques for making hierarchical data more SQL-friendly, such as [nested sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420885/how-do-i-design-a-database-to-store-properties-selecting-attributes-by-synonyms/7423459#7423459).